# 'Clever' ways of switching between GUI and CLI modes with `Gooey`

Tags: python, argparse

I'm putting together a first attempt at a GUI program that wraps a really basic script (so that someone less CLI-savvy can run it).

One thing I had hoped, was that the script would still be CLI-able for those that are so inclined, with identical options.

I'm using `Gooey` for this as it seems nice and simple for someone getting started, but now I'm stuck about how to go about 'toggling' it.

In order to use the GUI, a python framework binary has to be used to execute the script, so my first thought was to look for someone calling the script explicitly with a non-framework binary, and having the shebang point at `#!/usr/bin/env pythonw` the rest of the time. I think this works in principle, but at the moment I can only think to use a simple if-else for the test.

This is fine, however, the `@Gooey` decorator requires the use of `GooeyParser` not `ArgumentParser` (from `argparse`). So at the moment, this would mean I need my whole argument ingesting function twice in the code, which feels decidedly non-pythonic.

e.g:

```
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

@Gooey(program_name="Hi I'm progam X")
def gui_args():
    """Parse GUI arguments"""    
    parser = GooeyParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "-f",
        "--file",
        action="store",
        widget="FileChooser",
        help="Some input file."
        )


from argparse import ArgumentParser
def get_args():
    """Parse command line arguments"""    
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "-f",
        "--file",
        action="store",
        help="Some input file."
        )

def main():
     if <some_framework_python_test>:
          args = gui_args()
     else:
          args = get_args()
```

**Is there a clever way I can switch between the GUI and CLI behavior without having to duplicate code, based on how the code is launched?**

Other ideas I had include toggling the decorator based on some other threads, but its quite complex, and I would also need to switch `GooeyParser` to `ArgumentParser` in the actual code. Or perhaps `Gooey` already provides for this and I'm missing something obvious (I know for instance, `Gooey` handles argparse-style help formatting.

I don't know much about framework python either, so I don't know if what I'm proposing would work. Open to all suggestions! At the moment, running the code without specifying a `pythonw` binary just throws an error that `Gooey` can't find a screen.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/296

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as I expected, there most certainly was a 'clever'/elegant way.

There is a (currently) undocumented option `--ignore-gooey` which will make the script behave as a normal python script.

An [issue has been created on the github repo](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey/issues/449), and the author is going to document this in the not too distant future.

`Gooey` actually spits this argument out in the terminal as a full representation of the command that was run, with all the arguments provided in the GUI, which was how I noticed it, when dispatching the actual code to be run.

In the interests of a comprehensive answer, if you ordinarily called your GUI program like so*:

```
$ pythonw MyGooeyScript.py
```

to launch a full GUI session, you can instead call it like so:

```
$ pythonw --ignore-gooey  MyGooeyScript.py <options>
```

*It is sometimes necessary to launch python in unbuffered mode, with `-u`.

Comment: Don't you mean
`$ pythonw MyGooeyScript.py --ignore-gooey <options>`
?